# How long after applying orange oil to my Grandmother's old desk should I stain it?

Tags: furniture

I have inherited my grandmother's old childhood desk. This a desk that has been heavily used its whole life. I have sanded it down, finishing with 400 grit. I used wood condition by Minwax. Then restained it, came out horrible. I sanded it all back down, again finishing with 400 grit. But during the second of sanding, I noticed just how dried out the wood was. So this time I used orange oil. Sprayed onto my clean cloth and wiped on. The wood soaked it quicker then I could wipe it on. I did a second coat 24 hrs later. This time it soaked it pretty quickly but not a quickly as before. I had treated the WHOLE desk; the under belly, inside the draws, the interior where the goes (drawer cavities). Waited a bit I then wiped it down with a clean white cloth and no oil residue is on the cloth.
My question:
How long should I wait before restaining? Or is there anything I need to do before restaining?
I have restored lots of antiques and never had such a difficult time as this desk is giving me.

Comment: Sanding to 400 grit in effect polishes the wood closing the grain and causing it to reject the stain.

Answer (score 1):

From the [craftsman’s blog](https://thecraftsmanblog.com/how-to-prep-wood-for-stain/)

> A lot of folks make the mistake of sanding to either too fine of a grit or not fine enough before applying stain. Too fine and the wood won’t be able to accept the stain. Too rough and the wood will be very dark almost to the point of being black.
>   So, what’s the right grit? Generally speaking, for woods like oak and pine, I don’t like to go any finer than 120-grit or any rougher than 100-grit. Stay close to that range and the wood should look great.

Comment: I was not aware of the use of orange oil as a restorative for raw wood. I have used tung oil and know of the use of linseed oil, but not orange oil as a sealer. I have used orange oil as a cleaner/mastic remover. If the wood will still take oil, maybe you should apply tung oil  over the orange oil to keep the orange oil from reacting with the varnish. If you sand with 100 or 120 grit, then maybe apply tung oil before an oil based varnish. Personally I like a tung oil finish as the final finish. If it weathers, then you just reapply without stripping the old finish.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked wonderful. But I now have one question. The two end sides which are a different type of wood then the front and the top reacted to the tong oil after re-sanding and restaining. It lightened up. I want to retouch up with a little more stain. Should I sand again, stain and then use the lung oil? Or can I just straight to the staining?

Comment: @SilverKHolmes  depending on the type tungoil you used perhaps you can get it to darken with stain. Maybe test the same oil on a scrap of wood let it dry then try applying stain over it.  You may find https://forum.canadianwoodworking.com/forum/woodworking/finishing-and-refinishing/5673-stain-over-tung-oil helpful

Comment: Thanks. I will follow the link and try on a piece of scrap wood. I used Formbys oil.